# Prove every finite set of real numbers is well ordered.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

so as the title says how do we prove it? I mean it is obvious but i have no idea how to do it. Without referring to general principle of mathematical induction, as that would be circular logic i presume.

Comment: @avid19 Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Induction is in fact the way to do this; we induct on the number of elements in the set. The empty set is trivially well-ordered; any set containing exactly one real is well-ordered (if the set is $\{x\}$, the order is $x \leq x$, and that's a well-order).

Now, suppose we have a set $\{ r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n \}$, which are in ascending order. What is it for this set to be well-ordered? We need every subset to have a least element. But every subset is finite, so is (by inductive hypothesis) well-ordered unless it's the entire set, so in particular it has a least element unless it's the entire set. Together with the fact that the entire set has a least element (again by induction, since `min` is associative), that's all we need.

By the way, it is always possible to find a well-order on any finite set (even one which doesn't come with an order, like $\mathbb{R}$'s subsets do). This is also proved by induction on the length of the set.

Comment: Alright i see, also i have a question is it possible to prove this using the fact that every finite nonempty set has a largest element?

Comment: If you like. Apply the automorphism $x \mapsto -x$ to the reals and use the above argument.

Comment: To make this complete, I guess you want need to show that $\{r_1,...,r_n\}$ has a least element.

Comment: Yes, true. Fortunately $\{r_1, \dots, r_{n-1}\}$ does by induction, and $\min$ is associative.

Answer (score 0):

Every non-empty subset of the naturals is well ordered with respect to the standard ordering on the naturals. If $A$ is any non-empty finite set, then there is a bijection $f:A\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Given two elements $a,b\in A$, say $a\leq_Ab$ if and only if $f(a)\leq f(b)$. Then $\leq_A$ defines a well ordering on $A$.

To see why this is the case, it is a total ordering on $A$:

Reflexive: We have $a\leq_A a$ for all $a\in A$ since $f(a)\leq f(a)$ for all $a\in A$.

Transitive: If $a,b,c\in A$ and $a\leq_A b$ and $b\leq_A c$, then $f(a)\leq f(b)\leq f(c)$ so $a\leq_Ac$.

Anti-Symmetric: If $a\leq_A b$ and $b\leq_A a$, then $f(a)\leq f(b)$ and $f(b)\leq f(a)$ so $f(a) = f(b)$. $f$ being bijective implies $a=b$.

Strongly connected (or total): If $a,b\in A$, then $f(a)\leq f(b)$ or $f(b)\leq f(a)$ so $a\leq_Ab$ or $b\leq_A a$.

Now, given any non-empty subset $B\subseteq A$, $f(B)\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and has a minimal element, say $m\in f(B)$. Then $m\leq x$ for all $x\in f(B)$. Given $b\in B$, we have $m\leq f(b)$ hence $f^{-1}(m)\leq_A b$ for all $b\in B$ so $f^{-1}(m)$ is the minimal element of $B$. This shows that $\leq_A$ is a well ordering on $A$.

Answer (score 0):

This is overkill, but just for fun, a set is well-ordered iff it contains no infinite sequence $x_0, x_1, ...$ such that if $i > j$ then $x_i < x_j$. A finite set of real numbers contains no such infinite sequence and, as such, it is well-ordered.

Comment: You need to assume some choice for this, though. It is consistent that an infinite subset of the reals does not have any infinite sequences which are not periodic.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not seen as a redundant to Patrick Steven's answer...it just provides a little extra detail on how the induction argument takes place.

We want to show that for any for any $n \in \mathbb N$, if $S_n$ is a set with $n$ elements (all belonging to $\mathbb R)$, then $S_n$ has a least element (i.e. $S_n$ satisfies the well-ordering principle). A similar argument can be used to show that $S_n$ must have a greatest element. Formally, we will show through induction that $\forall n \in \mathbb N:\left[ \forall S: \big( |S|=n \rightarrow \exists x^* \in S: \forall x \in S: x^* \leq x \big) \right]$

**Base Case**

Consider any arbitrary singleton $S_1=\{x\}$. Clearly, $x$ is the least element of $S_1$.

**Inductive Assumption**

For an arbitrary $n$, suppose we know that for any $n$-sized set $S_n$, there is a least element $x_{\ell} \in S_n$.

**Induction Proof**

Consider any arbitrary $S_{n+1}$. Choose any $t \in S_{n+1}$. Then there exists an $S_n: \{t\} \cup S_n=S_{n+1}$. By our inductive assumption, we know that there is an $x_{\ell} \in S_n$ such that for any $x \in S_n: x_{\ell} \leq x$. There are two cases to consider:  $t \geq x_{\ell}$ or $t \lt x_{\ell}$. In the former case, we have that for any $x \in S_{n+1}: x_{\ell} \leq x$, so $x_{\ell}$ is the least element of $S_{n+1}$. In the latter case, we have that for any $x \in S_{n+1}: t \leq x$, which means that $t$ is the least element of $S_{n+1}$. In either case, we therefore have that there exists a least element for $S_{n+1}$. $S_{n+1}$ was arbitrary, so we can generalize to any $(n+1)$-sized set $S_{n+1}$. The induction is now closed.

We can now generalize across the natural numbers and claim that for any $n$-sized set $S_n$, there is a least element $x_{\ell}$.